# Awk column with pattern array

Tags: awk

Is it possible to do this but use an actual array of strings where it says "array"

```
array=(cat
dog
mouse
fish
...)

awk -F "," '{ if ( $5!="array" ) { print $0; } }' file
```

I would like to use spaces in some of the strings in my array.
I would also like to be able to match partial matches, so "snow" in my array would match "snowman"
It should be case sensitive.

Example csv

```
s,dog,34
3,cat,4
1,african elephant,gd
A,African Elephant,33
H,snowman,8
8,indian elephant,3k
7,Fish,94
...
```

Example array

```
snow
dog
african elephant
```

Expected output

```
s,dog,34
H,snowman,8
1,african elephant,gd
```

Cyrus posted this which works well, but it doesn't allow spaces in the array strings and wont match partial matches.

```
echo "${array[@]}" | awk 'FNR==NR{len=split($0,a," "); next} {for(i=1;i<=len;i++) {if(a[i]==$2){next}} print}' FS=',' - file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brief approach using a single regexp for all array contents:

```
$ array=('snow' 'dog' 'african elephant')
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | awk -F, 'NR==FNR{r=r s $0; s="|"; next} $2~r' - example.csv
s,dog,34
1,african elephant,gd
H,snowman,8
```

Or if you prefer string comparisons:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

array=('snow' 'dog' 'african elephant')

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" |
awk -F',' '
    NR==FNR {
        array[$0]
        next
    }
    {
        for (val in array) {
            if ( index($2,val) ) {      # or $2 ~ val for a regexp match
                print
                next
            }
        }
    }
' - example.csv

$ ./tst.sh
s,dog,34
1,african elephant,gd
H,snowman,8
```

Comment: Thats perfect thanks. How could I do the reverse? Print if there is no match.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure you could figure that out with a couple minutes of thought (hint: the "not" symbol is `!`) but if you can't then ask a new question as everyone hates [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: I think it needs to go in this line but not sure how. `if ( index($3,val) )`

Answer (score 1):

This prints no line from csv file which contains an element from array in column 5:

```
echo "${array[@]}" | awk 'FNR==NR{len=split($0,a," "); next} {for(i=1;i<=len;i++) {if(a[i]==$5){next}} print}' FS=',' - file
```

Comment: Is it possible to have strings with spaces in my array? What about partial matching? So "snow" in my array would match "snowman". Should have mentioned these in the OP.