# remove lines matching blacklist array

Tags: awk, printf

**I have this which prints lines where the 3rd column matches a value in my array.**

```
blacklist=('dog'
'cat'
'fish'
'african elephant')

printf '%s\n' "${blacklist[@]}" |
awk -F',' '
    NR==FNR {
        array[$0]
        next
    }
    {
        for (val in array) {
            if ( index($3,val) ) {
                print
                next
            }
        }
    }
' - $file
```

**File :**

```
dfd213,323,cat
90,65,dog
ddf,5hgf,hamster
jhg67,5f,fish
6h,ioo,indian elephant
5444h,fdh,african elephant
08,fd,mouse
09,dsd,macaw
```

**Output :**

```
cat
dog
fish
african elephant
```

**How can I alter it to print lines that are not matched instead?**

**Wanted output:**

```
hamster
indian elephant
mouse
macaw
```

Comment: @tripleee: Guess it looks alright now? Reopen?

Comment: I'm afraid I see no improvement. It looks like the OP has no idea how this code works, and is asking for free code writing services.

Comment: That's just a copy of the script I provided in [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60077634/1745001). Please update your question to show what you've tried to accomplish your new task so we can help you figure out where you're misunderstanding it and how to do what you want.

Comment: yes that's right. If I understand it correctly the line I need to edit is `if ( index($3,val) )` I would expect `if != ( index($3,val) )` to work but it does not. I dont really understand the double brackets and the comma. I assume the comma means it uses either value?

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk -v bl="${blacklist}" -F, '{flag=0; split(bl,a,","); for (i in a)  if ($3==a[i]) flag=1; } {if(flag==0) print $3}'  file
```

```
  :>cat file
   dfd213,323,cat
   90,65,dog
   ddf,5hgf,hamster
   jhg67,5f,fish
   6h,ioo,indian elephant
   5444h,fdh,african elephant
   08,fd,mouse
   09,dsd,macaw
   :>blacklist="dog,cat,fish,african elephant"
   :> awk -v bl="${blacklist}" -F, '{flag=0; split(bl,a,","); for (i in a)  if ($3==a[i]) flag=1; } {if(flag==0) print $3}'  file
   hamster
   indian elephant
   mouse
   macaw
   :>
```

Please note I have passed array as `,` seprated